# when activate odd-16 environment manyally that wkhtmltopdf tools working good. When create odoo-16 service, when i run with sytemctl i face that issue

Tags: linux, systemd, odoo-16

Wkhtmltopdf works manually: I confirmed that Wkhtmltopdf functions correctly when manually activating the Odoo 16 environment, suggesting the binary itself and basic functionality are likely okay.
Issue with systemd service: when I run the Odoo service through systemd

Wkhtmltopdf works manually: I confirmed that Wkhtmltopdf functions correctly when manually activating the Odoo 16 environment, suggesting the binary itself and basic functionality are likely okay.
Issue with systemd service: The problem arises when running the service through systemd, indicating a potential configuration mismatch between manual and service execution.

Comment: issue "Report
Unable to find Wkhtmltopdf on this system. The report will be shown in html.<br><br><a href="http://wkhtmltopdf.org/" target="_blank">wkhtmltopdf.org</a>"

Comment: Please include a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem in a way others can reproduce.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.